# Can I pass reference as array item in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, reference, parameter-passing

I want to pass references in array to a function in JavaScript, like this:

```js
class MyClass {
  // ...

  myfunc(['str1', 'str2'], [this.companies, this.devizas, this.paymentTypes]);

  // ...
}
```

The in `myfunc` is something like this:

```js
function myfunc(firstArg: string[], references: any[]): void {
  const payload: any[] = [];
  // payload's content coming from an observable and length will be equal to `reference` array

  for (let i = 0; i < payload.length; i++) {
    references[i] = payload[i];
    // here I want to pass value payload[0] into the caller class this.companies field
  }
}
```

Now - if I think right - in this way the `references[i] = payload[i];` line is overwrite the reference with a value, and not load up the value into the reference.

Is there any way to pass references in array and the fill the reference with value?

Comment: No, you can't do that in JS so you can't do it in TS. You're making an array of the values those properties resolve to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do you think, is there any other way / best practice to solve this problem? I want to avoid the destructuring in `MyClass` actually.

Comment: Pass `this` and the property *names*, maybe? Or return the values from `myfunc` and let `MyClass` itself decide what to do with them. With so little real context it's hard to say.

Comment: `this` will be the winner! Thank you!